# GTK3 Python Hbox Expand Option Doesn't Work

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I have a button which contains a `hbox(2)`.

I've added `pack_start` with these options:

```
self.hbox.pack_start(self.label, True, True, 0)
self.hbox.pack_start(self.icon, False, False, 0)
```

It shows:

[image]

While I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your HBox homogeneous property is true.

Comment: @jku Thank you so much. I've set it to False, now it works fine.